# scanf terminating standard input

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char str[20];
    int number;
    while(2 == scanf("%s  %*d %*s  %*s    %d %*d %*s %*s %*s", str, &number)){
        printf("%s\n",str);
        printf("%d\n", number);

    }
}
```

I am trying to read multiple lines from standard input all of which have the same format. My current implementation works but I can't seem to figure out anyway to terminate the input once the user does not input a line and then presses enter. The program keeps expecting input from the user. Is there anyway to do this using `scanf` and with my current implementation?

NB: I am running commands like:

```
ls -l | my_program
```

and that is not giving me any output.

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: You should indicate EOF by typing Control-D on a Unix-like system or Control-Z on a Windows system.  The `%s` will skip leading white space, including newlines, waiting for non-blank characters.  Only EOF will make it stop.  If you want to do line-based input and stop on an empty or all blank line, use `fgets()` to read the line and `sscanf()` to parse it.  Note that on Unix, Control-Z suspends rather than terminates the process.

Comment: For example -ab--c--  7 Yes  No    1578

Comment: I only need to extract the -ab--c-- and 1578

Comment: Please add the information to the question — you can edit your own question.  What you've got is right for that; you just need to know how to indicate EOF.  If you redirected from a file (`./your_program < data.file`), then you'd have no problem.  At the terminal, you need to know to type the correct EOF-indicating control-key sequence.

Comment: Typically I use pipe.  cat testfile.txt | executable. However, the c program does not print anything. Sometimes I enter each line of the correct format individually but the input never terminates.

Comment: That's more surprising.  Maybe you'd better show (a cut down version of) `testfile.txt` in the question.  We really only need to see 3-5 lines.  You don't have any strings like `-abc-def-ghi-jkl-mno-pqr-stu-` which are longer than 19 characters?  That would overflow `str` and wreak havoc.  Otherwise, you should be OK.  You test for `2 == scanf(…)` which is the correct test; you'll stop if you don't get a number where expected, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler cat file.txt | executable works, sorry my bad. I am actually trying to analyze file details in my program. The following does not work: \bin\ls -l | executable

Comment: Note that a single blank and multiple adjacent blanks in the format string do exactly the same job — the first skips optional white space and the others do nothing because the white space has been skipped already.

Comment: Backslashes in your path?  Are you on Windows?  My `ls -l` outputs 9 fields on a line — more if there are spaces in the file name (`-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  8744 Jan 19 21:21 rl43` for the program `rl43` that I created from your code).  Would you be better of reading lines and then parsing them?  I think you might be.  Anyway, on a Mac running macOS, I can repro the problem with `ls -l | rl43`.  I'll poke at it.  But, you're going to have problems; you need to skip the date (3 fields) and file name (1 or more fields) too.

Comment: Oh, of course: `ls -l` outputs a first line `total NNN` with the size.  That quickly screws your formats up (the `%s` reads `total`, the `%*d` reads `NNN`, the `%*s` reads the permissions, the `%*s` reads the link count, and the `%d` fails on the user name unless the user name happens to start with a digit (which would be unusual).  (Incidentally, one other advantage of reading lines — you can print the input and see what's going wrong.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the total line. Ill take care of the total line once I figure out how to deal with the other lines. The thing is I am restricted to using scanf and no functions such as strtok.

Comment: Can I make my current implementation work somehow given my restrictions?

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` unless you're obliged to.  It's a horribly tricky function to use correctly.   And it's difficult to identify errors well.  See also [A Beginner's Guide Away From `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).  You'll need a separate input statement to read the `total` line; you'll need more input to read the date and file name.  Remember that `scanf()` doesn't care about newlines; the output of `ls` requires you to parse on newlines.  You'd do better with `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Its part of a project and I am restricted to scanf.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please (re)read the [Ask] page, and note the guidelines for creating an MCVE ([MCVE]). It shouldn't have been so hard to find out that you're running `ls -l | ./your_program`; that should have been part of the initial question. Once the salient information is available, the problem is immediately resolvable. It is important to state restrictions like "must use `scanf()` and cannot use other input functions" up front. People will suggest the best way to do things unless they are told that you don't have any option about using it. Please remember for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the simplest modification using only [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) to read the output from `ls -l` command is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[20];
    int number;
    if (scanf("%*[^\n]") != 0)
        return 1;
    while (2 == scanf("%s %*d %*s %*s %d %*[^\n]", str, &number))
        printf("%s  %d\n", str, number);
    return 0;
}
```

The first `scanf()` read up to but not including the newline; that skips the `total NNN` line that `ls -l` outputs.
The second `scanf()` is almost the same as yours except that it skips the data after the second number (the file size) up to the newline.
Fortunately, the `%s` at the start skips leading white space, including newlines, so the fact that the scan sets `%*[^\n]` leave the newline behind doesn't matter in the slightest.

My directory yields:

```
$ ls -l
total 152
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff  22072 Dec 30 09:19 LICENSE.md
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff   2694 Dec 30 09:19 README.md
dr-xr-xr-x    4 jleffler  staff    128 Aug 14  2016 Safe
drwxr-xr-x   84 jleffler  staff   2688 Jan 12 00:58 Untracked
drwxr-xr-x   26 jleffler  staff    832 Dec 25 22:39 bin
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff   1875 Jan 19 00:08 crseq71.sql
drwxr-xr-x   14 jleffler  staff    448 Dec 30 09:19 doc
drwxr-xr-x   10 jleffler  staff    320 Jan 12 01:13 etc
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff    173 Mar  3  2017 get.jl.activity
drwxr-xr-x   21 jleffler  staff    672 Jan  7 23:02 inc
drwxr-xr-x    5 jleffler  staff    160 May 28  2017 lib
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff    390 Jun 21  2017 makefile
drwxr-xr-x    4 jleffler  staff    128 Jan 12 01:13 packages
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff    218 Oct 15 10:18 pending.20171015.101828
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff   8704 Jan 19 21:39 rl43
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff    248 Jan 19 21:39 rl43.c
drwxr-xr-x    3 jleffler  staff     96 Jan 19 21:21 rl43.dSYM
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff   2247 Jan  6 22:44 sll43.c
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff    126 Oct 24 12:52 so-4689-5145.info
drwxr-xr-x  227 jleffler  staff   7264 Jan 19 11:34 src
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff     92 Jan 19 21:20 testfile.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff    645 Jan 18 23:37 union71.c
$ ls -l | ./rl43
-rw-r--r--  22072
-rw-r--r--  2694
dr-xr-xr-x  128
drwxr-xr-x  2688
drwxr-xr-x  832
-rw-r--r--  1875
drwxr-xr-x  448
drwxr-xr-x  320
-rw-r--r--  173
drwxr-xr-x  672
drwxr-xr-x  160
-rw-r--r--  390
drwxr-xr-x  128
-rw-r--r--  218
-rwxr-xr-x  8704
-rw-r--r--  248
drwxr-xr-x  96
-rw-r--r--  2247
-rw-r--r--  126
drwxr-xr-x  7264
-rw-r--r--  92
-rw-r--r--  645
$
```

Comment: Thanks.  Since the OP used `%*d` and `%*s`, there's not much need to explain to them that the `*` suppresses an assignment, and the conversion specification is not counted in the return value from `scanf()`.  The answer does mention scan sets and uses assignment-suppression again — and has a link to the POSIX documentation for `scanf()` which covers the points in detail.

Comment: Gotcha...good enough. Yes OP used it - expected that OP knows.

Comment: I also see that the OP edited the format string shortly before I edited the question to add the  `ls -l | program` information.  Originally, it didn't have all the trailing fields after the `%d`.  It doesn't matter much.  Using the `%*[^\n]` scan set deals comprehensively with the rest of the line, even if there are blanks in the file name which the code now in the question doesn't handle well.