# scanf disregard input past certain point

Tags: c, scanf

Is there any way to disregard all input for the current line past a certain point? This meaning if scanf read:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukasz lukasz  423 Jan 19 01:49 Make file
```

is there any way to just disregard all input past 423? I am currently working on a program that reads this line format, and I am having trouble with spaces in file names. This meaning that make is read, then file will be carried over into the next scanf iteration.

Comment: Read a whole line, use `sscanf` to parse it, move on. There's nothing left over then.

Comment: `%*[^\n]` will do the trick. It does leave the `\n` on the input, but that's usually taken care of by the next `scanf`.

Comment: you might try `FILE *fp = fopen( "filename", "r" );  char buffer[ 1024 ]; fscanf( fp, %1023[!\n'], buffer );` Which will input characters until 1023 characters input -or- a '\n' is encountered.  Of course, the code would need to check (!=NULL) the contents of `fp` to assure the call to `fopen()` was successful.  Of course, the code would need to check the returned value from the call to `fscanf()` (in this case, anything other than 1 would be an error)

Comment: @user3629249: you mean `fscanf(fp, "%1023[^\n]", buffer);`? Note however that this format will fail to read an empty line, leading to potential undefined behavior as `buffer` is not modified. Using `fgets()` is much simpler and safer.

Comment: @chqrlie, your right about using `^` rather than `!`.  However, if the file is empty or at EOF, then the returned value will not be 1.  So such events would be caught,.

Comment: See [`scanf()` terminating standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352813/scanf-terminating-standard-input/48353008#48353008); that too is code trying to parse `ls -l` output and ignoring everything after the size field.  The answer shows the same technique @chqrlie uses.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here?  I just set up seven variables s1 ... s0 and ran this:

```
scanf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s0);
```

and it puts out the list

```
-rw-rw-r--
1
lukasz
lukasz
423
Jan
19
01:49
Make
file
```

whenever I have something like this to do, I read the whole line and process the pieces with strtok.

--- update---

What happens if there are multiple spaces in the filename or if the name starts with a space?  If you are guaranteed that the filename will not start with a space, this will work:

```
char linein[200];
char s[12][12];
char *p;
char *in=linein;
char *file;
fgets(linein,sizeof(linein), stdin);
for(int ii=0; ii<8; ii++) {
    p=strtok(in," ");
    in=NULL;
}
file=strtok(in,"\r\n");
printf("file=%s\n", file);
```

Comment: That works when there is one (and only one) sequence of white space in the file name.  It doesn't work well when there's no spaces in the file name, nor when there's more than one sequence of white spaces in the name.

Comment: Yes.  The first scanf version will only work if there one and only one space in the filename.  The strtok version works for zero or more spaces but this is all for answering the question.  If you want to walk a directory tree, you would use readdir with some other logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the rest of the input line with 2 conversions specifiers at the end of your format string: `%*[^\n]%*c`:

- `%*[^\n]` reads all characters up to the newline and discards them (this is what the `*` is for)
- `%*c` reads and discards the newline.

Note however that this method will fail it there are no characters to read before the newline. You can work around this with 2 separate calls to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
scanf("%*c");
```